# How to Redirect to a certain route based on condition in Angular 2.

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-meteor

I am creating one angular2-meteor app.

```
export const routes: Route[] = [{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: "login",
    pathMatch: "full"
}, 
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
}, 
{
    path: 'csvtemplate',
    component: TemplateComponent,
    canActivate: ['canActivateForLoggedIn'],
    children: [{
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard' <----how to add condition for multiple path
    }, 
    {
        path:'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'csvtimeline/:month/:year',
        component: CsvTimelineComponent
    }, {
        path: 'csvjson',
        component: CsvJsonComponent
    }]
}];
```

When i login to my app using LoginComponent it will go to TemplateComponent which have three child components

- dashboard
- csvtimeline
- csvjson

Now i have by default set redirectTo to my dashboard component. but in place of this redirect i want to redirect to csvjson component or csvtimeline component based on login user profile.

Suppose

**If Login User is "Admin" he should be redirectTo - > dashboard Component**

**If Login User is "Guest" then he should be redirectTo - > csvjson component**

i know we can do this in ngOnInit() of dashboard component for redirect.

```
if (this.user && this.user.profile.role == 'Guest') {
             this._router.navigate(['csvtemplate/csvjson']);
        }
```

but i am looking for better option so i don't have to open dashboard component each time and it will directly go to csvjson component.

Comment: Use a guard maybe ?

Comment: Why not make the redirction directly on your LoginComponent?

Answer (score 28):

Here is the better solution: **Guard the admin feature** according to Angular guide.
**Using CanActivate hook**
Steps:

### **1) Add auth-guard.service.ts file**

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate }    from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    canActivate() {
        //Your redirect logic/condition. I use this.

        if (this.user && this.user.profile.role == 'Guest') {
         this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        }
        console.log('AuthGuard#canActivate called');
        return true;
    }
    //Constructor 
    constructor(private router: Router) { }
}
```

### 2) Update the routing file, in my case it's app.module.ts

```
import { AuthGuard } from './auth-guard.service';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,

    RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
          path: 'admin',
          component: AdminComponent,
          canActivate:[AuthGuard]
        },
        {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
       }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Reference **
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard

Comment: Good solution, but not exact, in this case too if user knows the url of prohibited route lets say `csvtimeline` than he is able to go there by simply adding url in browser. this logic just redirect to router based on login condition nothing else

Comment: What if you define the prohibited path in RouterModule and set its caActivate property like this ..                                                                      RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
          path: 'csvtimeline',
          component: AdminComponent,
          canActivate:[AuthGuard]
        }, .....every time a user redirect to csvtimeline, the canActivate function will be called and there u have written a condition and u can redirect the user to any page you want.

Comment: Could you, please, let me know what should be returned from the `canActivate`?

Comment: **Note:** It is not considered good practice to navigate inside a route guard. If you want to redirect somewhere else you should instead return a `UrlTree` (or `Promise<UrlTree>|Observable<UrlTree>`).

Answer (score 4):

In routing module, u need to create local variable "route",check condition and assign requires routing path the variable
and assign variable to redirectTo in routing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

var route: string = "user";
const role = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")).roleId;

if (role == "1") {
//superadmin role
 route = "project"
} else {
  //normal user role
  route = "user"
}
const adminRoutes: Routes = [ {
path: '',
component: AdminComponent,
canActivate: [AuthGuard],
children: [

  { path: '', redirectTo: route },
  {
    path: 'project',
    loadChildren: './project-dashboard/project-dashboard.module#ProjectModule'
  }, {
    path: 'user',
    loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule',
  }
```

Comment: This will break when user logs in/out after module has been initialised

Comment: this is the perfect answer, because it easily solve the problem

Comment: What about asynchrony? and what if I just change localstorage roleId to admin even if I am a user?

Comment: this is during loading. and we need that condition check during running.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use resolvers combined with an "dummy" component:

```
const SwitchResolver: ResolveFn<any> =
  (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
    const user = inject(UserService).getUser();
    const router = inject(Router);
    if (user && user.profile.role == 'Guest') {
      router.navigate(['csvtemplate/csvjson']);
    }

    return of(null);
  };

@Directive()
class EmptyComponent {
}

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    resolve: { switch: SwitchResolver },
    component: EmptyComponent
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rip3rs jwt tokens are used for that only. you can logout your user if change is made in role from "user" to "admin"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Angular now recommands to use functional guards and flagged CanActivate as deprecated. Considering this, an easy way to answer the question is to do the following :

```js
const rootGuard = () => {
  const router = inject(Router)
  if (inject(AuthServiceService).isAuthenticated()) {
    router.navigate(['welcome']); // Default URL when logged
  } else {
    router.navigate(['login']); // Default URL when not logged
  }
}

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: AppComponent, canActivate: [rootGuard] // Any component would do
    // More path
  }
];
```