# Using a function in the router's "redirectTo" to determine where to redirect prevents aot

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using a function to determine where the user should be redirected on the loading of the site. Like so:

```
{   path : '', redirectTo: redirector(),     pathMatch: 'full' }
```

`redirector()` returns a route (string) eg: `'home/browse'`

This causes the following issue with `ng build --prod --aot`

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid configuration of route ''. One of the 
following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or 
loadChildren
```

Comment: did you find a solution for that

Comment: Use Angular's `CanActivate` on the route and put your redirect logic there. It's essentially route middleware.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Here you can see a github issue that also is related to angular guard (conditional) redirection.](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13373)

The example solution from the github issue is (also mentioned by [@David Alsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4040931/david-alsh) in the comments earlier):
`{path: '', pathMatch: 'full', children: [], canActivate: [RedirectGuard]}`

And then in the `RedirectGuard`'s `canActivate` method you could use: `this.router.navigate()`, where `this.router` is the `Router` from `'@angular/router'`: https://angular.io/guide/router, in order to execute the redirect.

[Example use of `this.router.navigate()`](https://angular.io/guide/router#navigating-back-to-the-list-component):
`this.router.navigate(['/heroes']);`

You can find even more details in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933619/how-to-redirect-to-a-certain-route-based-on-condition-in-angular-2).

Good luck!